# $C(A)\subseteq C(B)$ Meaning To Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let there be $A,B\in M_{m\times n}(F)$ and $C(A)\subseteq C(B) $ where $C(A)$ means the column space

Prove: there is $C\in M_{n\times n}(F)$ so that $A=BC$

That can be shown by matrix multiplication: $C(A)\subseteq C(B)\rightarrow$ the columns of A are linear combinations of the columns of B $\rightarrow$ there are $A^i=c_{ij}B^j\rightarrow$ there is a matrix $C=(c_{ij})$ such that A=BC.

can I solve it using rank notion?
$C(A)\subseteq C(B)\rightarrow$ $Rank(A)\leq Rank(B)$ therefore there is a matrix $C\in M_{n\times n}(F)$ so $Rank(A)=Rank(BC)$

And using linear transformations?
Can I say that $C(A)\subseteq C(B)\rightarrow$ $Im(A)\subseteq Im(B)$ can I countine from here?

Comment: Please, define $C(A)$ otherwise your question can be put on hold.

Comment: Probably the column space, but it should be clarified.

Comment: sorry, edited it is the column space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C(X)$ refers to the column space of $X$ and $C(A)\subseteq C(B)$, then the $i$th column of $A$ can be expressed as a linear combination $\sum_j c_j^i b^j$ of columns $(b^1,\ldots, b^n)$ of $B$. Then $C=c_j^i$ makes the job.

From linear transformation point of view, you can argue as follows. $C(A)\subseteq C(B)$ implies $\mathrm{Im}(A)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}(B)$, so for each $x$ there is an $y$ so that $Ax=By$. Choose a basis $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and find the corresponding $y_1,\ldots, y_n$ so that $A e_i=B y_i$. There is a unique $n\times n$ matrix $C$ for which $y_i=C e_i$ for all $i$, so $A e_i=BC e_i$ holds for a basis $(e_1,\ldots, e_n)$, so it holds for all vectors and $A=BC$.

Comment: thanks, I am trying to understand it form linear transformation point of view